# libstdc++.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line

Tags: c++, linux

I have started learning C++ on Ubuntu. I am only a few months into using Linux as well.

I am attempting to port over a 2D Ball Collision Script from Javascript to C++ for learning purposes.

I am using simple2D for the drawing in C++: https://github.com/simple2d/simple2d

I go to run this command:

```
simple2d build c-code-test.cpp
```

I receive this response:

```
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-std=c11’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++

/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccl07DBG.o: undefined reference to symbol '_ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev@@GLIBCXX_3.4'

//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Due to how fresh I am with Linux and C++ I am unable to make the correct inferences to solve this based on previous questions on stack overflow. I have installed libstdc++6 so I would have though it would be linked correctly.

Can someone walk me through in steps 1, 2, 3 ... Please? Thank you kindly!

Comment: Please refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). This isn't a tutorial or "1-2-3-..." type of site.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The errors you see look to be from trying to compile C++ as C.  The command line option is selecting the C11 standard, which is for C, not C++.  The missing symbol is because the C++ library isn't being linked in, which also happens when linking a program as C.

I haven't used simple2d, but my guess here is that the compile script they wrote does not support C++ or there is some option you need to use C++.  If we look at docs:

> The simple2d build command is a helpful shortcut for compiling a
>   single source file. Of course, you can also use a compiler directly,
>   for example on Unix-like systems:
>
> cc triangle.c `simple2d --libs` -o triangle

Why don't you try something like their example that invokes the compiler directly.  But you would need to use `g++` instead of `cc`.  Something like: `` g++ c-code-test.cpp `simple2d --libs` -o c-code-test ``

Comment: Thanks Trent, it looks like the code compiles when inputting this g++ c-code-test.cpp `simple2d --libs` -o c-code-test

Comment: Interestingly `--help` output or similar (as found in the script source) suggests that the input is "C/C++"

Comment: [This does seem to be a bug in the script](https://github.com/simple2d/simple2d/blob/master/bin/simple2d.sh#L209)

Comment: Yes this library is according to the docs supportive of C++. Looking at your bug reference it would seem that the issue is that. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I have submitted an issue, and a PR. https://github.com/simple2d/simple2d/issues/118

Comment: I wonder about the long term wisdom of trying to maintain a cross-platform script for compiling code.  It's a lot of work.  That's why a huge amount of effort has gone into build systems like autotools, cmake, meson, etc.

Comment: The fix has been merged.

Answer (score 1):

**This is [a bug with the simple2d script](https://github.com/simple2d/simple2d/issues/118).**

They're basically using the wrong build command for C++.

You could work around it by patching in the fix I've linked to, or using the manual build step shown by TrentP.

Or wait for the next version after v1.1.0.